# how to cover the status bar in iOS7 having a UITabBarController and UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, storyboard

**Introduction:**
The root problem i'm facing is the way iOS7 deals with the status bar "discriminately" with regards to `UINavigationController` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html) (quote in italics, the important part in bold):

*beginning with iOS 7 view controllers are displayed full screen, by default, as shown in Figure 1. This means they will cover the entire screen including the area underneath the status bar.*

[image: Figure 1 Full screen view controller underneath the status bar]
**Figure 1**  Full screen view controller underneath the status bar

[image]
**Figure 2**  Shows the view below the status bar, similar to the pre-iOS 7 behavior.

**Applications that use an opaque UINavigationController or UITabBarController automatically keep their content below the status bar.**

**Problem:** My root controller view is a `UITabBarViewController`.. and one of it's viewcontrollers is a `UINavigationController`, which in turn has a `UITableView` as its rootViewController. This relationship is illustrated here:

[image]

running this, the statusbar appears white:

[image]

instead of the other view controllers (that don't have the navbar + tableview):

[image]

based on the bolded quote above.. this makes perfect sense.. since iOS7 brute forces the uinavbar and all it's subviews below the status bar..

typically the way I address this problem (and i've read many many answers on SO about this problem) is by making my rootviewcontroller have a view that contains the color (in this case red) that i want to appear beneath status-bars in pages like the one above.. however I don't know how to do that when my rootViewController is a `UITabBarViewController`.. ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around all sorts of solutions.. I found that subclassing `UINavBar` and overriding its `layoutSubviews` to stretch its height solved the problem:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64);
}
```